# How to prevent direct bash script execution and allow only usage from other script?

Tags: bash

I have one script with common functions that is included in other my scripts with:

```
. ~/bin/fns
```

Since my `~/bin` path is on the PATH, is there a way to prevent users to execute `fns` from command line (by returning from the script with a message), but to allow other scripts to include this file?

(Bash >= 4)

Comment: Axel has given a good solution. But another question remains: if it is not supposed to be executable, why do you put it in the PATH in the first place?

Comment: Just for convenience. All executable scripts are in the same folder, so one/two non-executable files would not make a difference.

Comment: @AndreasBombe The `source` built-in also utilizes `PATH`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just remove the executable bit with `chmod -x . ~/bin/fns`. It will still work when sourced, but you can't call it (accidentally) by its name anymore.

Comment: dumb me, sometimes i cant see the obvious :)

Answer (score 4):

Some scripts at my workplace use a special shebang

```
#!/bin/echo Run:.
```

which returns

```
Run:. <pathname>
```

when you use it as a command.

Comment: I would be curious to see how this special case would work if you have an example..

Comment: I just saw this after seven years, and I really like the idea. This is cool!

Answer (score 3):

Add the following at the beginning of the script you want to be only allowed to be sourced:

```
if [ ${0##*/} == ${BASH_SOURCE[0]##*/} ]; then 
    echo "WARNING"
    echo "This script is not meant to be executed directly!"
    echo "Use this script only by sourcing it."
    echo
    exit 1
fi
```

This will check if the current script and executed shell script file basenames match. If they match, then obviously you are executing it directly so we print a message and exit with status 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (return 0 2>/dev/null) ; then
    :
else
    echo "Error: script was executed."
    exit 1
fi
```